# Is it possible to place a component underneath another one inside a RelativeLayout?

Tags: android

I want to create a `custom title` for a `Dialog` :

```
public class MessageDialogView extends Builder {

    private View view, titreView;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public MessageDialogView(Context context,LayoutInflater inflater) {
        super(context);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.msg_dialog, null);
        this.setView(view);
        titreView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_title, null);
        this.setCustomTitle(titreView);
    }
    ...
}
```

Layout of custom title :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    style="@style/ImpotsTitleStyle"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icone"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_warning"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/titre"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        style="@style/ImpotsStyleText"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

At runtime the title text is not "centered" in context of the whole entire title bar because there is the icon at its left !

[image]

So if I put the icon and title's text inside a `RelativeLayout` , is it possible to place the TextView underneath the icon ? If so what xml attribute is suited for that ?

Comment: Use `FrameLayout` in place of `LinearLayout`. Give the ImageView `layout_gravity="left"` & the TextView ``layout_gravity="center"``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a `RelativeLayout` is the correct solution for this. You can align the `ImageView` to the left and then have `TextView` centered at the same time. I've modified your code to point you in the right direction.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/ImpotsTitleStyle"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icone"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_warning"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/titre"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        style="@style/ImpotsStyleText"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```